# Event listener not creating cookie

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some JavaScript so that when a checkbox is clicked, a event listener creates a cookie. So far the event listener is created but does not generate a cookie.

JavaScript:

```js
function dailycomCookie() {
    'use strict';
    var dailycomValue = document.getElementById("commisions").value;
    document.cookie = "dailycomValue" + dailycomValue;
}
document.getElementById("commisions").addEventListener("change", dailycomCookie);
```

Comment: Did you forget to add a `=` sign? `document.cookie = "dailycomValue=123;";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set a cookie you need to use a `key=value` format (see [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)).

also, you don't really need to get the element again, you can use the event inside the function

so this should work:

```
function dailycomCookie(e) {
    'use strict';
    document.cookie = "dailycomValue=" + e.target.value;
}
document.getElementById("commisions").addEventListener("change", dailycomCookie);
```